How has iTalki, etc., been impacted by the advent of ChatGPT?
I'm curious as to how foreign-language online teaching sites/apps like iTalki have been impacted by ChatGPT and generative AI.
Question: How has iTalki, etc., been impacted by the advent of ChatGPT?
A related question was asked on Reddit here (September 2023), where there's comments in both directions:

... As it has become easier to self-study, demand for language teachers has increased. ...

and in response to the question "Is Chatgpt making italki teachers irrelevant?":

I think so... unfortunately. I say this as a language teacher myself. I've been doing this for over 12 years. I think it is time to start preparing for a new job, honestly.

It'd be nice to get some data here.
